# jPlayer not function correctly with

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have been using the [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) for a while successfully and according to their site I needed to update to version 2.5+ for  security reasons. I have done this and although I can get it to work I have one issue, when I use the jquery no conflict it won't work on FireFox 19/20 but will on 21+ and won't work on Opera but works fine on IE, Safari and Chrome.

Here is a link to the player;

If I take out the;

```
var jq=$.noConflict();

noConflict:"jq",
```

and change jq back to $ it works fine, but then of course if I add anything else that uses jquery to the page they conflict and one won't work.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this, apparently in jPLayer 2.5+ you need to include .jQuery in the name set as noConflict. So like this

```
var jq = {jQuery: jQuery.noConflict(true)}
jq.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
        {
            title:"Track 1",
            mp3:"track1.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Track 2",
            mp3:"track2.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Track 3",
            mp3:"track3.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Track 4",
            mp3:"track4.mp3"
        },
    ], {
        noConflict:"jq.jQuery",
        swfPath: "",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

So

```
var jq=$.noConflict();
```

becomes

```
var jq = {jQuery: jQuery.noConflict(true)}
```

and

```
jq(document).ready(function(){
```

becomes

```
jq.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

and finally

```
noConflict:"jq",
```

becomes

```
noConflict:"jq.jQuery",
```